# MPI - Partition processors so that one program runs on N processors and the other on M processors

Tags: mpi

How would I configure a program using MPI so that I split the total number of processors into M groups.

E.g. Using a command such as:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

In a file tree that looks like the following where all `*.out` files are configured to run using MPI

```
a.out
b.out
c.out
```

And within the program:

```
Processors 0 and 1 -> ./b.out
Processors 2 and 3 -> ./c.out
```

Comment: You have two processes running `b.out` and two `c.out`. So where does that leave `a.out`? You want to start that program, but no one is running it?

Comment: Try the MPMD syntax: `mpirun -np 2 ./b.out : -np 2 ./c.out`. An other option is to build a single binary (makes `b.out` and `c.out` subroutines so to speak) and `MPI_Comm_split()` and invoke the appropriate subroutine.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout the user calls `./a.out` - `./b.out` and `./c.out` can also be treated as libraries that cannot be directly called by the user

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am not familiar with `MPI_Comm_split()` could you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score -2):

Check this out.
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/

Thread affinity can help you.  Basically assign certain ranks to certain cores.

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer the question.